# Can I use full text indexing on a view?

Tags: indexing, sql-server-2000, full-text-search

I am using SQL Server 2000 and I am using full text indexing on a table. Can I use full text indexing on a view of this table?
If yes, then how can I use?
If no, then what should I do?

Actually, I am doing refinement of the results obtained from a table and for this refinement I am using a view of this table...

Answer (score 3):

No, you cannot use full text indexing on the view of a table.

You can apparently create one on an [indexed view though](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=121108).

See also: [Creating an Indexed View](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933148.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create full text index on view. Here is the idea for the creating a view.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263071?sort=votes

Comment: The question is about SQL Server 2000 not 2005.