# Force indexing of a filestream in SQL Server 2012

Tags: filestream, sql-server-2012, full-text-indexing, filetable

Is it possible to force somehow the indexing service of MS SQL Server 2012 to index a particular filestream/record of a filetable?

If not, is there any way to know if a filestream/record has been indexed?

Thank you very much!

Edit: I found something. I'm not able to index a single file, but I may be able to understand what files have been indexed.

using this query: [`EXEC sp_fulltext_keymappings @table_id;`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645845.aspx) you'll know every record that has been indexed, is better than nothing...

Comment: You should post your edit as a potential answer since it solves your problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It *sounds like*  you want to *full text* index a subset of the files within a single file table. (If it's otherwise, clarify your question and I'll edit the answer).  There are two ways you could approach this.

One approach, is to use two distinct `FileTable`s (`MyTable_A` and `MyTable_B`), place the files you want indexed in `MyTable_A`, and the non-indexed ones in `MyTable_B`.  Then apply a full text index to A, but not B.   If you need the files to appear in a unified fashion within SQL, just gate access through a view that `UNION`s the two filetables.   A potential pitfall is that it requires two distinct directory structures.  If you need a unified file system structure this approach won't work.

Another approach, is to create an `INDEXED VIEW` of the files you want to full text indexed.  Then apply a full text index to the view.  *Disclaimer:* I have not tried this approach, but [apparently](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=121108) [it works](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/263071/creating-a-fulltext-index-on-a-view-in-sql-server-2005?sort=votes).